# JBoss 6/JasperReports Classloading Issue

Tags: jasper-reports, classloader, jboss6.x

I'm having an issue with class loading in JBoss 6 with Jasper Reports. We have a multi-ear application where two of the ears each include a copy of jasperreports-4.5.0.jar (jar versions are identical, as shown by md5 checksum) in a lib folder at the root of the Ears.

Things had been humming alone fine until about 3 weeks ago when someone on the team did a mass check-in to change some date/time formatting. Since then, attempts to run a Jasper Report from one of the ears always fails with the same stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:82) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969) [:5.1.0]
at com.landslide.reports.LandslideReport.printJasperReport(LandslideReport.java:411) [:]
at com.landslide.reports.LandslideReport.generateReport(LandslideReport.java:362) [:]
at com.landslide.reports.LandslideReport.exportToByteStream(LandslideReport.java:228) [:]
at com.landslide.reports.LandslideReport.exportToByteStream(LandslideReport.java:217) [:]
at com.landslide.common.delegate.MyListDelegate.createPDFDocumentForMyList(MyListDelegate.java:2491) [:]
at com.landslide.scheduledreport.ScheduledReportRun.getPdfFromMyList(ScheduledReportRun.java:367) [:]
at com.landslide.scheduledreport.ScheduledReportRun.run(ScheduledReportRun.java:197) [:]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [:1.6.0_39]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [:1.6.0_39]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_39]
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Class net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry does not implement/extend net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsRegistry
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:56) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.createDefaultRegistry(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:81) [:5.1.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.<clinit>(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:69) [:5.1.0]
... 19 more
```

Attempts to use the Jasper Reports functionality from the other ear work fine.

When the offending ear is deployed by itself, all is well. I am guessing that somehow the class loading has gotten "confused" and that when the attempt is made to initialize the Jasper Extensions Registry, the interface class either can't be found or is coming from the other ear's jasper library and is failing the Jasper instantiateClass call.

I've tried reving the Jasper libraries to the newest version (5.1.0) as well as tried using jboss.classsloading.xml files in the war's included in the ears, as well as the ears themselves, in an attempt to force class loader isolation, but with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

-- Dave Swindell

Comment: That may be some classpath issue, maybe you have duplicated "jasper" libriaries deployed?

Comment: Each ear does have a copy of the jasperreports library, but I thought jboss was supposed to provide class loading isolation within each ear?